# Random select Radio button from multiple radio group

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I had 6 set of radio group and each group have 4 radio buttons.

```
function callRandom() {
    var check_group = []; // <<< Here
    var contestants = ["groupA", "groupB", "groupC", "groupD", "groupE", "groupF"];
    var contestantsNumber = contestants.length;
    var loop_number = 4;

    for (var i = 0; i < loop_number; i++) {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * contestantsNumber);
        var randomWinner = contestants[randomNumber];
        // var randomWinner1 = contestants[randomNumber];
        // var x = document.getElementById("winner");
        if (!check_group.includes(randomWinner)) { // <<< check here
            console.log(randomWinner);
            check_group.push(randomWinner); // <<< add to the check_group
            var array = document.getElementsByName(randomWinner);
            // console.log(array)
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            array[randomNumber].checked = true;
        } else {
            loop_number++;
        }
        console.log(array);
    }
}
```

Currently this code work perfectlyand it will select random 4 groups from array and random pick a radio button.
But i wan only select once from the array.
For example if groupA is selected, i dont wan to be picked agn.

**ps: I want display each selection. i wanna get [0] values until [3] values and display it in html. how to get the text"groupA"
[image]

as i have 6 sets of radio button groups,and i wan it to be selected 4/6 (without duplicate groupname)[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: please mark the answer as correct if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array with the selected groups and check if the group in the array or not

```js
callRandom();

function callRandom() {
  var check_group = [];   //<<<<<<<< Here
  var contestants = ["groupA", "groupB", "groupC", "groupD", "groupE", "groupF"];
  var contestantsNumber = contestants.length;
  var loop_number = 4;
  var the_random_array = []; var the_sorted_array = []; //<<<<< the arrays
  for (var i = 0; i < loop_number; i++) {
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * contestantsNumber);
      var randomWinner = contestants[randomNumber];
      // var randomWinner1 = contestants[randomNumber];
      // var x = document.getElementById("winner");
     if(!check_group.includes(randomWinner)){  // <<<<<<< check here
         //console.log(randomWinner);
         check_group.push(randomWinner);    // <<< add to the check_group
         var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
         // to check the random radio use the next line
         var get_radio_value = $('input:radio[name="'+ randomWinner +'"]:eq('+ randomNumber +')').prop('checked' , true).val();
         //Next Output randomly group
         //console.log(randomWinner , get_radio_value);
         the_random_array.push(get_radio_value); // random array
     }else{
      loop_number++;
     }
  }
  // Use The Next code if you want sorted groups from groupA to groupF not random
  $('input:radio[name^=group]:checked').each(function(){
    //Next Output from groupA to groupF
    //console.log($(this).attr('name') , $(this).val());
    the_sorted_array.push($(this).val()); // sorted array
  });
  console.log('From random array :'+the_random_array[2]);
  console.log('From sorted array :'+the_sorted_array[1]);
}
```

```css
.group_of_radio{
  margin : 10px;
  padding : 10px;
  background : #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="group_of_radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupA" value="groupa_1">GroupA _ 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupA" value="groupa_2">GroupA _ 2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupA" value="groupa_3">GroupA _ 3</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupA" value="groupa_4">GroupA _ 4</label>
</div>
<div class="group_of_radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupB" value="groupb_1">GroupB _ 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupB" value="groupb_2">GroupB _ 2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupB" value="groupb_3">GroupB _ 3</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupB" value="groupb_4">GroupB _ 4</label>
</div>
<div class="group_of_radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupC" value="groupC_1">GroupC _ 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupC" value="groupC_2">GroupC _ 2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupC" value="groupC_3">GroupC _ 3</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupC" value="groupC_4">GroupC _ 4</label>
</div>
<div class="group_of_radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupD" value="groupD_1">GroupD _ 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupD" value="groupD_2">GroupD _ 2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupD" value="groupD_3">GroupD _ 3</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupD" value="groupD_4">GroupD _ 4</label>
</div>
<div class="group_of_radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupE" value="groupE_1">GroupE _ 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupE" value="groupE_2">GroupE _ 2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupE" value="groupE_3">GroupE _ 3</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupE" value="groupE_4">GroupE _ 4</label>
</div>
<div class="group_of_radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupF" value="groupF_1">GroupF _ 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupF" value="groupF_2">GroupF _ 2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupF" value="groupF_3">GroupF _ 3</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupF" value="groupF_4">GroupF _ 4</label>
</div>
```

Comment: when i console this             
console.log(randomWinner); i can see it looping four times. How can i get values for each ?

Comment: i had update my questions (attached img) @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: @JesscyTey yes because you console.log before check the array ,, if you console.log inside the if statement it won't duplicate the value

Comment: i run the code agn and found its actually gt duplicate of group.. @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: @JesscyTey Please check my snippet .. Also I added `loop_number` because if the loop found a duplicated value it will not count so I increase it by one to match the 4 outputs you want

Comment: @JesscyTey what I understand you have a 6 different groups and each group has 4 radio inputs?? is that right??

Comment: Yes, i have 6 different groups and each has 4 radio input

Comment: @JesscyTey Ok so your problem is not to get the group text  your problem now is selecting the random input with name group .. Please wait a minute :-)

Comment: Cause i wanna to display: groupA => selection, groupB=>selection. SO when i trying to do             console.log(array)[0]; i still get 4. Is there any ways that i could get the value from [0]..to[3]. separately? 
  @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: @JesscyTey Ok leave the display right now .. let's focus on check a random input first .. updated my answer with `$('input:radio[name="'+ randomWinner +'"]:nth-child('+ randomNumber +')')` line  .. check it

Comment: @JesscyTey OR it will be much better to update your question with **html** and the **expected output**

Comment: @ Mohamed-Yousef the updated code is not working. i had update my code. the current code works nicely and it will check the radio button.My consent now is how to get each of the value from array instead of calling 4 of the values tgt. Cuz i wanna put each value in different div. Currently i will get straight 4 of the looped values.

Comment: @JesscyTey Did you try `console.log(array[randomNumber].value)`

Comment: @ Mohamed-Yousef but how to get array[0] value. array[2] values? I tried with with ur comment, i will get all of the values. but what if i only want to get [0] and [2] values in log?

Comment: @JesscyTey check my updated answer .. I added 2 console.log .. first one is randomly .. and the second is sorted from groupA to groupF

Comment: @ Mohamed-Yousef yeah, ur answer is correct. but nvm, i try to figure out how to get value from specific number of array.

Comment: @JesscyTey I got your point now give me one minute please .. you want the group in order/sorted or just randomly??

Comment: @JesscyTey answer updated with random and sorted arrays .. check it

Comment: Hi @ Mohamed-Yousef  Thanks god. this is what i wan!! Thank you~ You save my day

Comment: You're totally welcome @JesscyTey .. I think your next task is to return the array from the function and use the function like `callRandom()[0]` right?

Comment: my next task is to get the radio button val and display it to html will do. if i do $('input:radio[name^=group]:checked')[0] << can i get the value of radio button from this jquery? @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: Cuz there's img that i want to retrieve based on checked button value. SO its easier if i able to get the value of radio button haha

Comment: @JesscyTey `$('input:radio[name^="group"]:checked:eq(0)').val()`